# How to clone selected divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, clone

Javascript report designer should allow to create copies of selected divs into same panel.

I tried to use

```
function DesignerClone() {
    $(".ui-selected").each(function () {
            var newDiv = $(this).prop('outerHTML'),
                parentpanel = $(this).parent(".designer-panel-body");
            parentpanel.prepend(newDiv);
    });
}
```

but all divs are lost. and empty panel appears.
To reproduce, run code snippet and select some divs by mouse click.
After that press clone button.

How to clone boxes ?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <style>
        .designer-panel-body {
            min-height: 1px;
            overflow: hidden;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        .panel-footer {
            background-color: inherit;
        }

        .designer-panel,
        .designer-resetmargins {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        .designer-verticalline,
        .designer-horizontalline,
        .designer-rectangle {
            font-size: 1pt;
            border: 1px solid #000000;
        }

        .designer-field {
            border: 1px solid lightgray;
            white-space: pre;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        .ui-selecting {
            background-color: lightskyblue;
            color: white;
        }

        .ui-selected {
            background-color: lightskyblue;
            border-color: darkblue;
            color: white;
        }

        .designer-label {
            white-space: pre;
        }

        .designer-field,
        .designer-label {
            font-family: "Times New Roman";
            font-size: 10pt;
            z-index: 2;
        }

        .designer-verticalline,
        .designer-horizontalline,
        .designer-rectangle,
        .designer-field,
        .designer-image,
        .designer-label {
            position: absolute;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <script>
        function DesignerClone() {
            $(".ui-selected").each(function () {
            var newDiv = $(this).prop('outerHTML'),
                parentpanel = $(this).parent(".designer-panel-body");
            parentpanel.prepend(newDiv);

            });
        }

        function getpos(e) {
            return {
                X: e.pageX,
                Y: e.pageY
            };
        }

        function Rect(start, stop) {
            this.left = Math.min(start.X, stop.X);
            this.top = Math.min(start.Y, stop.Y);
            this.width = Math.abs(stop.X - start.X);
            this.height = Math.abs(stop.Y - start.Y);
        }

        $(function () {
            var startpos;
            var selected = $([]),
              offset = {
                  top: 0,
                  left: 0
              };
            $(".designer-verticalline, .designer-rectangle, .designer-field, .designer-image").resizable();
            var $liigutatavad = $(".designer-verticalline, .designer-horizontalline, .designer-rectangle, .designer-field, .designer-image, .designer-label");
            $liigutatavad.draggable({
                start: function (event, ui) {
                    var $this = $(this);

                    if ($this.hasClass("ui-selected")) {
                        // if this is selected, attach current offset
                        // of each selected element to that element
                        selected = $(".ui-selected").each(function () {
                            var el = $(this);
                            el.data("offset", el.offset());
                        });
                    } else {
                        // if this is not selected, clear current selection
                        selected = $([]);
                        $liigutatavad.removeClass("ui-selected");
                    }
                    offset = $this.offset();
                },

                drag: function (event, ui) {
                    // drag all selected elements simultaneously
                    var dt = ui.position.top - offset.top,
                      dl = ui.position.left - offset.left;
                    selected.not(this).each(function () {
                        var $this = $(this);
                        var elOffset = $this.data("offset");
                        $this.css({
                            top: elOffset.top + dt,
                            left: elOffset.left + dl
                        });
                    });
                }
            });

            // ...but manually implement selection to prevent interference from draggable()
            $(".designer-panel-body").on("click", "div", function (e) {
                if ( /*!e.metaKey &&*/ !e.shiftKey && !e.ctrlKey) {
                    // deselect other elements if meta/shift not held down
                    $(".designer-panel-body").removeClass("ui-selected");
                    $(this).addClass("ui-selected");
                } else {
                    if ($(this).hasClass("ui-selected")) {
                        $(this).removeClass("ui-selected");
                    } else {
                        $(this).addClass("ui-selected");
                    }
                }
            });

            $(".designer-panel-body").selectable({});
        });
    </script>

</head>

<body>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="javascript:false;DesignerClone()">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-paste"></span>
    </button>


    <div class='panel designer-panel'>
        <div class='panel-body designer-panel-body panel-warning' style='height:4cm'>
            <div class='designer-field' contenteditable='true' style='top:2.30cm;left:5.84cm;width:10.24cm;height:0.63cm;font-family:Arial;font-size:14pt;font-weight:bold;'>vnimi+&#39; &#39;+dok.tasudok</div>
            <div class='designer-field' contenteditable='true' style='top:2.30cm;left:16.37cm;width:2.68cm;height:0.61cm;font-size:14pt;'>DOK.kuupaev</div>
            <div class='rectangle' style='border-width: 1px;background-color:#FFFFFF;top:2.99cm;left:1.34cm;width:18.05cm;height:5.29cm'></div>
            <div class='designer-field' contenteditable='true' style='top:3.01cm;left:1.53cm;width:9.71cm;height:0.55cm;font-size:12pt;'>m.FIRMA</div>
            <div class='designer-field' contenteditable='true' style='top:3.01cm;left:12.13cm;width:3.13cm;height:0.53cm;font-size:12pt;'>ise.telefon</div>
        </div>
        <div class='bg-warning'>
            <div class='panel-footer'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up'></i> GroupHeader 1: str(dokumnr)+str(koopia,2)</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `.clone()` does the job nicely.

Comment: add .clone() after the parent part

Comment: @AdamAzad I replaced line in DesignerClone to `$(this).parent(".designer-panel-body").appendTo($(this).parent().clone().html())` but whole panel content is still cleared

Comment: @RST . I was unable to make clone work. I tried to clone using html. In this case cloned box is not visible. How to fix this ? I updated question using html cloning

Comment: do you have a working model somewhere?

Comment: You can press run code snipped in question. It looks like jquery ui selectable(), resizable() and draggable() have added classes to div which prevent added div to be visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.appendTo` takes selected element and removes it from previous position in the DOM.

[jQuery.clone()](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) is what you might be looking for.

Comment: I tried replaced cloning line to `$(this).parent(".designer-panel-body").appendTo($(this).parent().clone().html())` but whole panel is still created by this comand.

Comment: no, `$(this).parent(".designer-panel-body").clone()` instead `$(this).parent(".designer-panel-body").appendTo`

Comment: clone() didnt work, probably I missed something simple. So I tried to clone using html. It looks like in this case object is cloned properly but it is not shown. How to make cloned div visible? I updated DesignerClone() method in question to use html to clone

Comment: @Andrus ok, you have edited code in question, let me see what have you done

Comment: it seems that added div contains jquery ui resizable, selectable, draggable classes which make div invisible. If `<div>Hello</div>` is inserted it is displayed properly. Should new div created without those classes and resizable, draggable and selectable methods applied to new div after it is created? Also new div position should be different from original div by few pixels to make both visible.

Comment: @Andrus dude, your function `DesignerClone` is supposed to iterate over each `".ui-selected"` which - doesn't exist anywhere in the HTML code / DOM?

Comment: Jquery-UI selectable adds this class if clicked in div element.